Divider in Form does not extend all the way across on macOS
I have this SwiftUI Form:
var body: some View {
    Form {
        TextField("One label", text: $field1)
        Divider()
        TextField("Another label", text: $field2)
    }
}

On macOS, the Divider does not extend all the way across the Form, instead stopping to the right of the input labels. How can I make it go all the way?

Here's a screenshot to illustrate what I'm trying to do:


Wait, there are 3 bugs about Form now? oh no. Bug 1 and Bug 2.

I believe this is how Forms work on macOS. Can you find any system apps where the divider extends to the full width in a form? From what I can find, most forms don't use dividers at all. Most system forms seem to use spacing to divide different sections.

@Sweeper System apps, no, but I've attached a screenshot of the app Front and Center which does what I'm trying to do.

The Front and Center app's author, John Siracusa, is a well-known personality in the macOS community. You might try tooting at him or emailing him to ask how he implemented that dialog. You can find his contact information on his web site.
Anyway, it can be difficult to get exactly the layout you want with SwiftUI. Many things that were possible and (in my opinion) relatively simple with autolayout are much, much harder to do in SwiftUI. In particular, Form allows very little customization on macOS and if you don't like the way it lays out your controls, you usually end up having to abandon Form entirely and find a different way to lay out your view.
In this case, you can get a good approximation of the screen shot by using Grid instead of Form and, fortunately, it doesn't even require shenanigans like a custom Layout or PreferenceKey or even a GeometryReader. Here's my result:

Here's the code:
import SwiftUI

struct GeneralTab: View {
    var body: some View {
        Grid(alignment: .leadingFirstTextBaseline) {
            GridRow {
                Text("Behavior:").gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                Picker("Behavior:", selection: .constant("Classic")) {
                    Text("Classic").tag("Classic")
                    Text("Something Else").tag("Something Else")
                }
                .fixedSize()
                .labelsHidden()
            }

            Text(
                """
                Classic behavior brings all of an app's windows to the front when one is clicked. Modern behavior brings only the clicked window to the front.

                To get the opposite of the chosen behavior, hold down the Shift key while clicking a window.
                """
            )
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .font(.callout)
            .foregroundStyle(.gray)

            Divider()

            GridRow {
                Text("Trigger:").gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                Picker("Trigger:", selection: .constant("Any Activation")) {
                    Text("Any Activation").tag("Any Activation")
                    Text("Something Else").tag("Something Else")
                }
                .fixedSize()
                .labelsHidden()
            }

            Text(
                """
                When set to Window Click, only app activations triggered by a click on a window will be considered. When set to Any Activation, all app activations will be considered.
                """
            )
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .font(.callout)
            .foregroundStyle(.gray)

            Divider()

            GridRow {
                Text("Interface:").gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                Toggle("Show Dock icon", isOn: .constant(false))
            }

            GridRow {
                Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                Toggle("Show menu bar icon", isOn: .constant(true))
            }

            GridRow {
                Text("Startup:").gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                Toggle("Open automatically at login", isOn: .constant(true))
            }

            GridRow {
                Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                Toggle("Hide on launch", isOn: .constant(false))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            GeneralTab()
                .padding()
                .tabItem { Text("General") }
            Text("exclude")
                .padding()
                .tabItem { Text("Exclude") }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            HStack {
                Text("1.4.1")
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                Spacer()
                HelpLink { }
            }
            .padding(8)
        }
        .padding(.top)
        .padding([.horizontal, .bottom], 20)
        .frame(width: 440)
    }
}

@main
struct testApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        Window("Front and Center", id: "f&s") {
            ContentView()
                .preferredColorScheme(.light)
        }
        .windowResizability(.contentSize)
    }
}

#Preview {
    struct PreviewView: View {
        var body: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }

    return PreviewView()
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
}


Wow, thanks for the amazingly thorough answer! Much appreciated.
